# Google Maps InfoWindow Z-Index

Tags: javascript, maps, z-index, infowindow

Is it possible for an InfoWindow to popup **over** an element which has a higher Z-Index than the google map?

So lets say the google map has a z-index of Zero. The element has a z-index of 100. 
Clicking a marker displays an InfoWindow in the same region as the element. How do we get this InfoWindow to hover over the element and not under it?

I have tried setting the InfoWindow's z-Index to a higher value, but this does not appear to do anything.

I've put together a demo below demonstrating the issue.
Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <title>Infowindow Z-Index Test</title>

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>                   
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>          

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var coords = [[35.50733, 35.12768, 3]]; //, [-23.806549, 133.96059, 13], [68.169002, -134.425964, 10], [69.529715, -132.109222, 10], [80.231047, -22.730713, 7], [35.108675, -117.961578, 12]];
        var map;            

        function mapChoose(coords) {
            var current = coords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (coords.length))];
            //mapShow(current[0], current[1], current[2], document.getElementById('map'));
            mapShow(current[0], current[1], current[2], document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
        };

        function initialize() {

            mapChoose(coords);
        }

        function mapShow(lat, lng, zoom, div) {
            var myOptions = {
                'zoom': zoom,
                'center': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                'disableDefaultUI': true,
                'scrollwheel' : false,
                'draggable': false
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            // markers
            // load markers - us
            var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.71435, -74.00597),
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/kitesurfing.png',
                draggable: true
            });
            marker3.setTitle("New York");                


            // info windows                
            var contentString = $("#divContentForInfoWindow").html();
            $("#divContentForInfoWindow").html('');


            infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString, zIndex: 5000 // this ZIndex property doesnt appear to do anything.
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function () {
                infowindow3.open(map, marker3);

            });

        };

    </script>

</head>


<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

    <!-- Google canvas element | Z-Index of 0 -->
    <div id="map_canvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 0;"></div>         


    <!-- Floating block of text | Z-Index of 100  -->
    <div id="FloatingBlock" style='z-index: 100;position: absolute;left: 50px;top:75px;font-size: 16px;width: 525px;text-align: left;color: #111;background-color:#fff;opacity:.80;filter:alpha(opacity=80);'>

        <b>This layer is floating above the google map because the Z-Index has been set higher. <br /></b>

        Hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br />
        hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br /> 
        Hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br /> 
        hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br /> 
        Hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br /> 
        hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world<br /> 

        <div class="text">

          <!-- <input type="button" id="btntest" value="Open Info Window" onclick="showInfoWindow2();" /><input type="button" id="btntest2" value="hide Info Window" onclick="hideInfoWindow2();" />-->
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </div>      
    <!-- / can delete this, not used -->

    <!-- everything IN here will appear in the google maps info window -->
    <div id="divContentForInfoWindow">       

        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />
        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />
        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />
        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />
        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />
        This is popup content. <br />This is popup content. <br />

   </div>
   <br /><br /><br />        
    <!-- / everything in here will appear in the google maps info window -->
</body>
```

Comment: You wont actually be able to adjust the z-index the way you're trying to. CSS parent children relationships won't let you. Basically as long as the map is a lower z-index then the floating block, the info windows can never be above it with this setup.

Your best bet, would be to try [CustomOverlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) or try to add your floating div into the map through the DOM

Answer (score 10):

use  infowindow.setZIndex(Number);

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted. Works for me. Full docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

Comment: IMHO this will not work when you deal with elements outside of the map. Every positioned element sets a new stacking context, so `z-index` won't get you very far in an environment with dozens of positioned elements. Better stick to lexie's answer.

Comment: @wortwart I agree, it won't work. Where is lexie's answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom-state) instead of outer element to place on the map. The custom control is placed above the map and when you open an InfoWindow, Google maps detects the position of the control and automatically moves and opens the InfoWindow below the control, so the both don't overlap. In this case it is better to use it instead of the [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow), because the overlay moves when you drag or zoom the map and the control always stays at the same position.

So, first you have to add the map and the control as div-s in your html, then to initialize the map and after that to add the control to the map like that:

```
var control = document.getElementById('control');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(control);
```

How simple is that ;)

Comment: i am creating a legend this way but info window hides behind legend , any idea what might be issue?

Comment: I am using several custom controls and the InfoWindow ignores them, frequently appearing underneath them. This solution does not work.